# my work on Wamp-access for other people

Tags: ip, wamp

I made a page in Wordpress on Wamp local server that I want to show the client.

I have a router Thomson and there I set port 80.![enter image description here][1]
..I dont know is this set up ok...
I applied the instructions on this link: How to access localhost of computers outside the network | Data Integrated Entity
and shut down (temporarily) Windows Firewall.

Now, when I gave a client on another computer my IP address / name of the project he see my work like a column with text, not really the page how really looks.
![enter image description here][2]

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you don't have php installed correctly, or there is something else wrong with your setup. In my opinion, it would be best to post your question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: You can use your actual IP in Wordpress, instead of "localhost". This is the fix: You can access it from the local network with a simple tweak: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21727715/1333791

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like your links for your css / images etc. aren't right

try show some images about the problem, a bit hard to help you when there aren't any images :)

Comment: I loved to send images but Stackoverflow said: " You need at least 10 reputation to post images". Im new here ;)

Comment: check your paths :) (that your css etc. is pointing to something :) (check it from another pc etc.)

Comment: hmmm it doesn t work but I decide to put my work on free server on line and when I import sql base I got this massage:SQL query:

--
-- Database: `test1`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'a9723716_termin'@'localhost' to database'test1'                                                                 What does it mean?

Comment: means you dont have access to the database :)