# Accessing local Wordpress site within the network using WAMP?

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp, vhosts

Allright this driving me nuts! I have spent couple of hours trying to find a solution of how to access my Wordpress site from outside my network, when no easy solution was found I'm OK with just being able to accessing it from another device within my network. It turned out to be a tricky part as well. I just don't know how to configure this.

I run virtual hosts using WAMP likeso:

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "I:\web_dev\wordpress"
    ServerAlias wordpress.local
    ServerName wordpress.local
    <Directory "I:\web_dev\wordpress">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require local
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

My httpd.conf file is set to port 80:

`ServerName localhost:80`

Hostsfile:

`127.0.0.1 wordpress.local`

If I now want to access this from another computer or my mobile that are in my network, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You should replace your local ip with your local network ip, it should be something like `192.168...` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

**Allow local traffic in httpd.conf, then use your actual IP as the WP URL.**

In WAMP's httpd.conf file, I added the `Allow from 192.168` line.

```
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168
```

Then in the WP General settings, I changed the `Wordpress Address` and `Site Address` to the site's actual IP. You can get this site's IP4 address via `ipconfig` in the command console.

**Then you're done.**

If you don't want people on your local network snooping around the rest of your WAMP setup, create a new `.htaccess` file in the servers root (the `www` folder) with this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Then add this above whatever is in WP's default `.htaccess`

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive to listen to the network IP or 0.0.0.0 rather than localhost if that is not yet done. 
Then on the other computer edit the hosts (usually `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts`) file to include the IP of the webserver computer mapped to wordpress.local

```
192.168.2.54 wordpress.local
```

Comment: In my host file of my webserver computer I have now changed: 127.0.0.1 wordpress.local to its IP instead which is: 192.168.1.2 wordpress.local. From the computer which Im trying to surf from I added 192.168.1.2 wordpress.local to its host file. I don't seem to be able to access it though. I tried to ping wordpress.local which gave a message of timeout. How come?

Comment: If a ping is timing out then either you have network connectivity issues or name resolution issues. Please try to directly ping 192.168.1.2 from the surfing computer. If this does not work, verify network connectivity and firewall settings. If this does work, verify the IP address shown when you ping wordpress.local is the IP address in the hosts file. Lastly, you may want to try to visit http://192.168.1.2 from your host computer, which shouldn't land at the wordpress site (due to vhosts) but should land you at _some_ page on that webserver.

Comment: From the host computer I can access 192.168.1.2 (unsurprisingly). I also can access my surfing computer from my host computer when pinging it, this in reverse though throw a timeout message. On my hosting computer my windows firewall are completely turned off while testing, no other firewall is used either.

Comment: Have you verified that you are listening on all interfaces by checking the Listen directive in httpd.conf? Have you verified the IP address you get when you ping from the surfing computer to wordpress.local is actually the IP of the host computer?

Comment: I start thinking the problem not has anything to do with WAMP since I can't ping my host computer in any way with WAMP turned off either? Hmm... Do I need to make any changes to 192.168.1.2 by opening ports or something?

Comment: That is correct, it sounds like you have a connectivity issue to that computer. You mentioned there is not firewall running on the host computer, so there wouldn't be anything to 'open' ports on. Can you attempt a traceroute to the IP from surfing computer. Use `tracert 192.168.1.2` in a command prompt and paste the output.

Comment: Thanks. Can I see the output of ipconfig /all (from cmd prompt) on the surfing computer and hosting computer.

Comment: Allright the problem was my router which is now replaced with only a switch. I can now access my local wordpress site from other computers on the network. I experience the speed quite slow though when visiting it from my mobile device? This really can depend on anything is my guess? Any ides where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of good tutorials on getting these setup:

1. View MAMP Virtual Hosts On Your iPad and iPhone Over The Local
   Network - BenjaminRojas.net http://goo.gl/6hM4Aa
2. How to access MAMP sites across a network - CodeBoxers
   http://goo.gl/qCXMQK (scroll down to the xip.io portion)

"The solution is to create a local proxy server on the machine that has MAMP installed, and then configure the client to use that proxy to browse the web. The client configuration only takes a few seconds, and is easy to disable once you’re done." - Dalton Rooney (from the first link)

Comment: My bad I didn't mentioned that I'm on Windows thus can't move any further with this great reply :(